# How to automatically update the grandtotal when quantity is changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout for my shopping cart and i cant seem to get the grand total to automatically update based on the change of an items.

**VIEW**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: cartItems">
 <div class="row item-row">
  <h3 data-bind="text: fullname"></h3>
  <p data-bind="text: sku"></p>
  <select data-bind="quantityDropdown: number, event: {change: $parent.updateqty}"></select>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <p class="checkout-box-totals">Subtotal:</p>
    <p class="checkout-box-price">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" data-bind="text: subtotal()"></span>
    </p>
</div>

<hr/>
<div class="row checkout-box-total">
    <p class="checkout-box-totals">Total:</p>
    <p class="checkout-box-price">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" data-bind="text: grandTotal()"></span>
    </p>

</div>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
    //This items placed in cart is placed in my cookiearray
    //cookiearray contains = datetime, id, typeid, qty, fullname, image, price, sku, weight)
    var cookiestring = $.cookie("cookieCart");
    var arrayfromJson = JSON.parse(cookiestring);

    //Deletes the cookie
    var deleteCookie = function (name) {
      document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
    };

    function UpdateCookieQty(id, typeid, select) {
       for (var i = arrayfromJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           if (arrayfromJson[i].id === id && arrayfromJson[i].typeid === typeid) {
               arrayfromJson[i].qty = select;
           }
       }
       //recreates the cookie string after updating the quantity. This new quantity isnt read in the observable until browser is refreshed.
       deleteCookie("cookieCart");
       $.cookie("cookieCart", JSON.stringify(arrayfromJson), { path: "/" });
   }



function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.cartItems = ko.observableArray(arrayfromJson);
    self.quantity = ko.observable(); //here im trying to make the quantity observable.
    var totalShipWeight = 0;

    //calculating total weight of the cart
    for (var n = 0; n < self.cartItems().length; n++) {
        var itemweight = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[n].weight, 10);
        var shipqty = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[n].qty, 10);
        totalShipWeight += itemweight * shipqty;
    }

    //calculating the subtotal doesn't update when quantity is changed :(
    self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.cartItems().length; i++) {
            var itemPrice = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[i].price, 10);
            var itemqty = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[i].qty, 10);
            total += itemPrice * itemqty;
        }
        return total;
    });

    //calculating tax if tax applies, doesn't update when quantity is changed
    self.taxedItems = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var taxcost = 0;
        var total = 0;
        if (totalShipWeight > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.cartItems().length; i++) {
                var itemPrice = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[i].price, 10);
                var itemqty = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[i].qty, 10);
                total += itemPrice * itemqty;
            }
            taxcost = parseFloat((total * tax).toFixed(2));
        } 
        return taxcost;
    });

    //calculating tax if tax applies, doesn't update when quantity is changed
    self.grandTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var total = 0;
        var grandTotal = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < self.cartItems().length; i++) {
            var itemPrice = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[i].price, 10);
            var itemqty = parseInt(arrayfromJson[i].qty, 10);
            total += itemPrice * itemqty;
        }
        grandTotal = total + (total * tax);
        //Add shipping cost
        return grandTotal;
    });

    //number = 50 from controller. this is just to display dropdown for max amount of quantity
    ko.bindingHandlers.quantityDropdown = {
        update: function (element) {
            for (var i = 1; i < number + 1; i++) {
                var selectedQty = "";

                for (var x = 0; x < self.cartItems().length; x++) {
                    var itemqty = parseFloat(arrayfromJson[x].qty, 10);

                    if (i === itemqty) {
                        selectedQty = " selected='selected'";
                    }
                }
                // Add each option element to the select here
                $(element).append("<option value='" + i + "' " + selectedQty + ">" + i + "</option>");
            }
        }
    };


    //this is where the user updates quantity. I goes to the function, 
    //updates quantity for particular item (but for some reason updates both items).
    //then the change is supposed to reflect in the subtotal and grandtotal, but doesnt.
    self.updateqty = function (viewModel, event) {

        UpdateCookieQty(this.id, this.typeid, event.target.value);
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Im fairly new to knockout but is there something wrong here?

Comment: When you update items (quantity or adding a new one to the cart) do you update an observable somewhere, or do you update the `arrayFromJson` cookie?

Comment: i only update arrayFromJson. Users shop around and add/remove items to that cookie. Then during checkout they can update quantity. when they change quantity im altering the cookie, but i need to alter the observables too so it matches what was edited in the cookie.

Comment: Turn it around: Do all your work in observables, and have a procedure subscribe to the observable(s) to update the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that you're only updating the `arrayFromJson` which is not something that knockout knows anything about, so it does not know it *needs* to update your `grandTotal` computed.  Not all of your code is showing, so I'm not sure the scope of all the functions and instances, but essentially you just need to tell knockout to recompute the `grandTotal` and ideally you would do that from your `UpdateCookie` function:

```
function UpdateCookieQty(id, typeid, select) {
   for (var i = arrayfromJson.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (arrayfromJson[i].id === id && arrayfromJson[i].typeid === typeid) {
           arrayfromJson[i].qty = select;
       }
   }
   //recreates the cookie string after updating the quantity. This new quantity isnt read in the observable until browser is refreshed.
   deleteCookie("cookieCart");
   $.cookie("cookieCart", JSON.stringify(arrayfromJson), { path: "/" });
   myAppViewModel.cartItems.removeAll();
   ko.utils.arrayPushAll(myAppViewModel.cartItems, arrayFromJson);
}
```

Note the `.removeAll()` and `arrayPushAll()` calls here, there's a common mistake people make with knockout that this avoids.  You want to make sure you're not doing: `myAppViewModel.cartItems = ko.observableArray(arrayFromJson);` here (again).  This replaces the original observable with a new one and abandons all the subscriptions that the `computed`s would have on the original instance.

Once that is done, then update your computed's to rely on the `cartItems` as it *is* observable, so knockout will detect the changes to that and then automatically recompute the values for you.

```
self.grandTotal = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    var grandTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.cartItems().length; i++) {
        var itemPrice = parseFloat(cartItems[i].price, 10);
        var itemqty = parseInt(cartItems[i].qty, 10);
        total += itemPrice * itemqty;
    }
    grandTotal = total + (total * tax);
    //Add shipping cost
    //Discount CMEZ
    return grandTotal;
});
```

Comment: hmm. ok i understand what you have there. forcing the newly edited cookies into cartItems. For some reason its not showing the grandtotal at all and when i update the quantity it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: AppViewModel.cartItems is not a function"

Comment: @NeoSketo Sorry, my knockoutjs is a bit rusty, I thought that was the syntax for updating the observable, but it's the syntax for a normal observable and not an array.  I will update my answer.

Comment: No problem, i really appreciate your help! ok so i updated my code but now where it says removeAll() its giving me "Cannot read property 'removeAll' of undefined" error. I think it just doesnt know what cartItems is in this context

Comment: @NeoSketo Yes that error indicaes that `cartItems` is `undefined`, is it possible the `UpdateCart` function is running before the view model is created?  It's hard for me to help with that without a better understanding of how your code is organized (and that is probably outside the scope of this SO question).

Comment: I see yeah that function is just above the ViewModel but that helps me figure out whats going on. I appreciate your help. maybe i can get it to work.